# free image and video thumbnail gallery wordpress

Tags: wordpress, image-gallery, video-gallery

Is there a free WordPress plugin for image and video gallery which supports thumbnails? I have been looking for ages but could'nt find anything which works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick Google search turned up [this](http://wordpress.org/plugins/flash-album-gallery/)

Comment: Thanks for the link, ill give it a try. I dont know how did i miss that. :P